Advice needed on becoming more observant as an adult
From a normative orthodox perspective, if a Jew is married to a convert who converted along with their infant in a Conservative synagogue (so not Jewish to them) which of these bad options are the "best":

The Jew follows as much halakhah as possible within the confines of the situation (shabbos, yom tov, kashrut, but not niddah for example)

If this, assuming I'd be only welcome at a Conservative synagogue, in which case being outwardly Jewish (ie wearing a yarmulke in public) would be misleading thus inappropriate, is this correct?


The Jew abandons observance of mitzvot

Note in this situation, the spouse is supportive but not interested in increasing observance. The child is in kindergarten and was refused a conditional conversion by modern orthodox. Divorce is not an option.
Looking for either an answer or books / online contacts to talk to about this. Extremely nervous to talk to a Rabbi about this question without knowing more first.

Most Orthodox synagogues will happily accept you and your yarmulke regardless of your specific level of observance. Certainly no one would tell you to abandon observance entirely. Judaism doesn't have a free membership tier.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

I've heard rabbis say that keeping a halacha observance is never hypocritical. But that approach implies that the hypocritical part is in the relationship. So this is a relationship dynamics question at heart. If your wife feels like the obstacle to you keeping your values, that may add an intolerable level of shame/pressure to the relationship. To avoid putting that over her, nothing from separation to conversion can be off the table, as you navigate a way for neither of you to have to give up your core values and beliefs.

And that also includes being clear in your mind about why Jewish observance is important to you, what level of precedence it takes for you. That way you can own the decision without it blurring into appearing to be something she is impeding. She may choose to be more observant or convert to take some complications out of the relationship, but she doesn't have to go against her own values regarding that either, so she needs to know that your choice, between the relationship and the halacha, has to be in your own hands rather than hers.
